# how do i use the pointer variable to change the value

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with changing the coordinate of the point to ( 7,4) using the pointer variable. I just did x = 7 and y = 4, but I don't think that is correct. Can someone help ?

What I need to do:

> - in main()
>
>   - instantiate  a Point object and initialize at the time of definition
>   - define a pointer that points to the object defined above
> - using the pointer variable to
>
>   - update the coordinates of the point to (7,4)
>   - display the distance from the origin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;

public:
    Point(int x_coordinate, int y_coordinate);
    int getVal();
    double distance(double x2, double y2);
};

// Initialize the data members

Point::Point(int x_coordinate, int y_coordinate)
{
    x = x_coordinate;
    y = y_coordinate;
}

// Get the values of the data members. 

int Point::getVal()
{
    return x,y;
}

// Calculates and returns the point's distance from the origin.

double Point::distance(double x2, double y2)
{
    double d;
    d = sqrt( ((x2 - 0)*(x2 - 0)) + ((y2 - 0) * (y2 - 0)) );
    return d;
}

//Allows user input and changes the point to (7,4) and displays the distance from origin.

int main()
{
    int x,y;

    cout << "Enter x coordinate followed by the y coordinate: " << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;

    Point p(x,y);

    Point *newPointer = &p;

    double theDistance = p.distance(x,y);

    cout << "The point's distance from the origin is: " << theDistance << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: `return x,y;` means `return y;`

Comment: @NickyC so i would need to make a new member that would change the numbers?

Comment: This doesn't seem a simple problem because member `x` and `y` are private and there is no setter for them. I guess we should use something like friend, inheritance, etc...

Comment: `Point` looks copy-assignable. Perhaps `*newPointer = Point(x,y)` will do.

Comment: @NickyC so i would need to assign the values(y= 7, x = 4), in Point?

Comment: @TheEWL Huh? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @NickyC so im just trying to figure out how to use the newPointer to assign the values that the user inputs to (7,4) or x=7, y = 4. And you told me that i should use a pointer->member. so im guessing i need to use newPointer and point to what?

Comment: Pretty sure @NickyC is pointing out a syntax problem. When using a pointer to access a member, you need to use -> not . p.distance should be p->distance.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I mean that exactly. No, `p` is the object, and `newPointer` is the pointer. (you know, the naming is confusing)

Comment: Okay i fixed that to newPointer->distance. Thanks! but any idea about my actual problem? ;/ @NickyC

Comment: Another comment of mine has talked about copy-assignment and `*newPointer = Point(x,y)`, hasn't it?

Comment: @nickyC yeah but that does not change them to 7 and 4

Comment: (sigh) How about `*newPointer = Point(7,4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update coordinates of point, you need a new function -

```
void Point::UpdateCoordinates(int x0, int y0)
{
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
}
```

For distance(), I think you only need below.

```
double Point::distance()
{
   return sqrt( x*x  + y*y );
}
```

Comment: so would i need to change the values in UpdateCoordinates to 7 and 4?
and i need to find the distance from the origin so one of the  x and y in that formula would need to be 0.

Comment: I didn't get you, shouldn't sqrt(x*x +y*y) be the distance between point(x,y) and (0,0)? Or actually you need the distance between two points(original and updated)?

Comment: @JianfengZhu The original question mentions "display the distance from the origin". I think the true problem is that the OP does not have a clear concept about things like variable or parameter or stuffs.

Comment: Agreed. Correct answer, but OP needs to do a bit more reading and learning of the basics to understand the answer.

Comment: @nickyC sorry. its all confusing to me.. so i input your  *newPointer = Point(x,y) and the distance does not seem to be comparing (7,4) to (0,0)..

Comment: @TheEWL Refer to **this answer**.

Comment: @nickyC wait yeah i got it! i know i was stressful to help with, but you guys all did really help. thanks guys